# Setting $JAVA_HOME as opc, not accessible as oracle

Tags: java, linux

I am currently with installing and integrating a couple of software on Linux, and I'm very new to Linux. One of the software refuses to run and instructs me to properly set $JAVA_HOME. But I have set $JAVA_HOME! However, when I check the $JAVA_HOME and java -version tests to see if I have done it correctly, it only produces the correct answer when I'm logged in as opc. The permissions of the software I am trying to install is oracle. Do I need to set $JAVA_HOME again when I'm logged in as oracle? And why?

```
[opc@mydir ~]$ $JAVA_HOME
-bash: /u01/jdk-11.0.3/: Is a directory
[opc@mydir ~]$ java -version
java version "11.0.3" 2019-04-16 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.3+12-LTS)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.3+12-LTS, mixed mode)
[opc@mydir ~]$ sudo su oracle
[oracle@mydir opc]$ $JAVA_HOME
[oracle@mydir opc]$ java -version
bash: java: command not found
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Environment variables (such as `$JAVA_HOME`) are set per process. For shells, you'd usually have some initialization script (like `.bashrc`) that sets all the relevant variables for the current session. You should copy the initialization of `$JAVA_HOME` you have in the `opc` user to the `oracle` user too.

Comment: How should I go about copying it? Because currently when I try to open .bashrc with oracle, it says permission denied.

Comment: I figured it out! I was opening the wrong .bashrc file. Thank you!